# How to aggregate and make a ratio between two fields from a CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which return a flag wheter a client who made a contract with my company this year is new or returning:

```
    WITH Resultset AS(    
    SELECT 
         Cnt = COUNT(*)
        ,KliRC --personal identification number
    FROM dbo.Smlouvy 
    WHERE VyplacenaCastka > 0
    GROUP BY KliRC
)
    SELECT
        s.KliRC
        ,CASE WHEN Cnt > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Novy --new client
        ,CASE WHEN Cnt = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Stavajici --existing client
    FROM Resultset JOIN dbo.Smlouvy s ON s.KliRC = resultset.KliRC
    WHERE (YEAR(DatumZadosti) = YEAR(GETDATE())) AND (s.KliRC NOT LIKE '%x')
```

Now, I need to aggregate all the new and existing clients and make a ratio between them.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make your main query another CTE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
WITH Resultset AS (    
      SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt,
             KliRC --personal identification number,
             (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Novy --new client
             (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Stavajici
      FROM dbo.Smlouvy 
      WHERE VyplacenaCastka > 0
      GROUP BY KliRC
  )
SELECT SUM(Novy) / SUM(Stavajici)
FROM Resultset r JOIN
     dbo.Smlouvy s
     ON s.KliRC = r.KliRC
WHERE YEAR(DatumZadosti) = YEAR(GETDATE()) AND
      s.KliRC NOT LIKE '%x';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query can be simplified to

```
SELECT SUM(Novy)*1.0/SUM(Stavajici)
FROM (
SELECT KliRC
,CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY KliRC) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Novy --new client
,CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY KliRC) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Stavajici --existing client
FROM dbo.Smlouvy
WHERE YEAR(DatumZadosti) = YEAR(GETDATE()) AND KliRC NOT LIKE '%x'
) T
```

Comment: According to Execution Plan it cost 4x less Memory then the other solution. However, then number of 50% new clients over existing ones is not correct.